# how to do an Angular2 Master Detail with firebase

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database

im getting this error : caused by: this.todoService.getKidsDetails(...).subscribe is not a function
TypeError: this.todoService.getKidsDetails(...).subscribe is not a function

here's my routing here with DetailinfoComponent as master detail component

```js
import {
  ModuleWithProviders
}
from '@angular/core';
import {
  Routes, RouterModule
}
from '@angular/router';

import {
  WorkersComponent
}
from './components/workers/workers.component'
import {
  AdminComponent
}
from './components/admin/admin.component'
import {
  KidsprofComponent
}
from './components/kidsprof/kidsprof.component'
import {
  HomeComponent
}
from './components/home/home.component';
import {
  AppComponent
}
from './app.component'
import {
  ContentManagerComponent
}
from './components/content-manager/content-manager.component'
import {
  DetailinfoComponent
}
from './components/detailinfo/detailinfo.component'
const appRouts: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  }, {
    path: 'kidsProf',
    component: KidsprofComponent
  },

  {
    path: 'detail/:id',
    component: DetailinfoComponent
  }

]

export
const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRouts)
```

Here's a Kids Component which get the id from routings

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    let id = this._route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.kidService.getKidsDetails(id)
      .subscribe(kid => this.kid = kid);
    console.log(this.kid);

  }
```

Service Which gets firebase data about a specific kid

```js
  public getKidsDetails(id) {
    return firebase.database().ref('kids/' + id).once('value');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on extracting the route params and using them in your kidService.

```
ngOnInit(){
   this._route.params
     .map(params => params['id'])
     .subscribe((id) => {
       this.kidService.getKidsDetails(id)
         .subscribe(kid => {
            this.kid = kid);
            console.log(this.kid);
             }
         })
     });
 }
```

And

```
public getKidsDetails(id) {
        return firebase.database().ref('kids/' + id).once('value')
             .map(response => response.json());
      }
```

Comment: im still getting the subscribe is not a function error

Comment: Is getKidsDetails(id) returning an Observable ? ( you can check with your IDE it usually tells you when you hover the mouse over the function).

Are you using Angular-Fire ?

Comment: i'm using pure firebase not angularFire.

Comment: My advice use Angular-Fire it is simple and improves your work with Firebase. 

Also as I remember when calling firebase did you append .json at the end of your call link ?  /something.json ?

One more thing I think you are missing the .map((response: Response) => response.json())  in your servic